# Why does this pattern occur when using modular arithmetic against set of prime numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, computer-science, random, pattern-recognition

I have been recently playing around with number theory and going through the project Euler problems. So I am very new to a lot of these things. I apologize for not knowing how to look up my answer. This is kinda a two part question I think.

First I created a list of prime numbers from 1 to ten million. Then I looped through this list up to about 350,000. In this loop I created a variable X for the prime number I was on, then another variable y for the for X + primeList[x]. each time I did this I calculated y mod x and saved that into a new list. I graphed that and got a strange pattern that I'm sure has to do with some basic concept of modular arithmetic that I just don't understand. I have included the screen shot of my graph below.

My python code:

```
for x in range(1,100000):
    start = primeList[x]
    mod = primeList[x+primeList[x]]
    result = mod % start
    primeModList.append(result)
```

As the second part of my question. I tried creating a pseudorandom list of numbers to kind of simulate the distributions of primes (I do understand this does not really work, but not sure of any other way to do it). I ran that same list through the same process and did not achieve the same results. Although if I increased my randomList[value] by the primeList numbers I did achieve the same result.

My code for this was:

```
for x in xrange(10000000):
    n = randint(0,10000000)
    randomList.append(n)

randomList.sort()

for x in range(1,100000):
    start = randomList[x]
    mod = randomList[x+randomList[x]]
    result = mod % start
    ranModList.append(result)
```

To reiterate I want to know why this pattern shows, and what major difference causes it to only show when increasing by number in my prime list and not my random list.

[My graph of the prime number set in blue, and my set of my remainders in green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxhLi.png)

Comment: primeList[n] is the $n$th prime, that we usually write $p_n$ ? and your primeModList is $r_n = p_{n+p_n} \bmod p_n$ ? then the distribution of $p_k \bmod p_n$ for $k > n$ is really not trivial, and I doubt $k = n+p_n$  yield such a nice (green) graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_n$ be the $n$'th prime, and let  $y_n = p_{n + p_{n}} \mod p_n$, i.e.
$p_{n+p_{n}} = x_n p_n + y_n$ where $0 \le y_n < p_n$ and $x_n = \lfloor p_{n+p_n}/p_n \rfloor$.   Now the point is that
$r_n = p_{n+p_n}/p_n$ will tend to grow, but
 slowly: $p_n \sim n \log n$, $p_{n+p_n} \sim (n + p_n) \log(n + p_n) \sim n (\log n)^2$, so $r_n \sim \log n$.  $x_n = \lfloor r_n \rfloor$ will typically be constant for long intervals.  For example, it is $12$ for 
$3070 \le n \le 7073$.  On an interval where $x_n = c$, $y_n = (r_n - c) p_n$
will tend to be increasing, from near $0$ at the beginning of the interval to near $p_n$ at the end.

Comment: overall you say that his green plot $y_n = p_n \{p_{n+p_n} / p_n\} $ is $\approx (n \log n)\{(n \log^2 n) / (n \log n)\} \approx (n \log n)\{ \log n\}$

Answer (score 0):

As far as your second question goes, I don't believe prime numbers are randomly distributed. For example, for primes greater than 2, a prime number can only be odd. Further, since every 3rd odd number is divisible by 3, the only potential primes are of the form $6k±1$, for $k\in\mathbb N$ (for primes greater than 3). Perhaps prime numbers are randomly distributed among those candidates, but not among the natural numbers themselves.